# Bootstrap 3 collapse with 2 cols

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have to cols (col-md-6) and want a collapse in each of this cols, but when I click on a panel each others won't close.
Here's an example code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="custom-collapse-0" class="panel-group">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a href="#collapse1" data-parent="#custom-collapse-0" data-toggle="collapse" class="accordion-toggle">TITLE</a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-collapse collapse in" id="collapse1" style="">
                    <div class="panel-body">TEXT</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a href="#collapse2" data-parent="#custom-collapse-0" data-toggle="collapse" class="accordion-toggle">TITLE</a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-collapse collapse in" id="collapse2" style="">
                    <div class="panel-body">TEXT</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can someone help me please?
Thanks

Comment: re-look at the documentation. There must be a parent specified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.bootply.com/7M5lUWZK6e

Here's a working example. I think the reason yours isn't working is because the column is not a part of the panel-default div. You will need to clear the padding on the panel.

```
<div class="row">   
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>   
</div>        
</div>
```

Comment: Weird, I tried the exact same thing earlier but using JS Fiddle, and I didn't post the answer because it screws with the coloring of the panel header. http://jsfiddle.net/nmw8ktr0/ Any idea why? Just a JS Fiddle thing?

Comment: If you clear padding on the panel with the column in it, it looks fine. See the Bootply CSS.

Comment: Very weird. I'll have to play with that later. +1 regardless.